# Help needed with linear algebra computation

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not see what is happening here.
$$(F^TF + \begin{bmatrix}V_1 & V_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\gamma &0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_1^T \\ V_2^T\end{bmatrix})^{-1}F^Ty = \begin{bmatrix}V_1 & V_2\end{bmatrix}\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}V_1^T \\ V_2^T\end{bmatrix}F^TF\begin{bmatrix}V_1 & V_2\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\gamma &0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\Bigg)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}V_1^T \\ V_2^T\end{bmatrix}F^Ty\\$$

Help that could explain this is appreciated :)

Comment: What is  $F$ ?  matrix or vector  ?? if vector , row vector or column vector  ?

Comment: all matrices, except for $$\gamma$$ which is a scalar

Comment: The term being inversed reminds me of the woodbury identity...